# Why are tasks split while updating plan?

Tags: ms-project, tasks, ms-project-2013

I inserted the actual start for updating a task and then inserted the %comp and reschedule and resource leveling for the plan with ms project 2013. The problem is that the task has been split in several parts without any reason, or the split parts reschedule too late whereas the predecessor has been finished and the constraint type is as soon as possible.

I know the rules of splitting in the calculation option and resource leveling and consider them all and even if I clear the leveling, the split parts of tasks aren't be corrected.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities come to mind: predecessor dependencies and resource calendars.

You said you added "actual start date" for the task and "% completed". When you do that, Project will move all the completed work of the task to the start date you set. However, the remaining work of the task will still follow task dependencies. You said the predecessor is completed, but to make sure check the "actual finish date" of the predecessor and see if it fits with the time of the split.

The other possibility is if you have any resources assigned to the task. If the resource calendar states that the resource cannot work on specific days (because of holidays for example), Project will interrupt the task when the resource isn't available and start again when the resource is available again. Open the resource and check its calendar to see if any non-working days are configured during that time period.